# Can someone explain to me why this output is given?

Tags: python

```
def recursion(n):
    if n < 10:
        return
    m = n/3
    recursion(m)
    print(m)

recursion(243)

OUTPUT: 9.0
        27.0
        81.0
```

I would expect the output to be 9.0 only...

How does putting a function in a function exactly work?
I.e. what it the flow of exection is this specific piece of code?

Comment: Please format your code as code so we can read it easier.

Comment: Why would you expect the output to be 9.0 only?

Comment: Recursive call is happening n function.format your code for more clearity

Comment: I voted this question up, because recursion *is* not easy to understand and I made enough mistakes myself using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the call tree of what happens:

```
recursion(243)
  recursion(81)
    recursion(27)
      recursion(9)
          return
      print(9)
    print(27)
  print(81)
```

As you can see, all the print statements are executed after all calls to `recursion`.
To only have `9` as output, you should just have `print(n)` in the `if` before the `return` and remove all the other `print`.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the value of `m` every recursion call, you can return the value insted and then print it as this:

```py
def recursion(n):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    m = n/3
    return recursion(m)

print recursion(243)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `print(m)` statement is part of every recursion step, not only the last one, so all of them will print their current value of `m`. If you only want it to print the last step, put the `print` statement before the `return` statement (into the break condition).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you expect wrong.

You have a print statement that is executed on every level of the recursion except the last, so that's what you get.

Answer (score 0):

First round :
n = 243 so it's greater than 10
m = 243/3 = 81

Second round:
n = 81 so it's greater than 10
m = 81/3 = 27

Third round:
n = 27 so it's greater than 10
m = 27/3 = 9

Fourth round:
n = 9 it's lower than 10 so return

```
1 - Printing m of third round (9)
2 - Printing m of second round (27)
3 - Printing m of third round (81)
```

This result makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling recursively your function and printing your numbers stacked before if you want to only see the last number you must put the print on your if

```
def recursion(n):
    if n < 10:
        print(n)
        return
    m = n/3
    recursion(m)
```

These code will print only 9.0

If you want to see the flow of your function use these and you must see the trace

```
def recursion(n):
    print("stacking")
    if n < 10:
        print(n)
        return
    m = n/3
    recursion(m)
    print("unstack")
```